# A shape that focuses light from the widest range of incidence angles into a smaller area

Tags: solar-energy, solar

I remember reading about devices which were roughly hyperboloid in shape that had the property of focusing light from a much wider range of incidence angles than a parabollic antenna. I think they were used to power solar stirling engines. Id like to read about those again but i dont remember what these devices were called. Does anyone know what im talking about?

Comment: In general, these are non-imaging systems.  They maximize total irradiance within a specified radius on the image plane, rather than a resolvable image.

Answer (score 1):

The general term for these are [Compound Parabolic Concentrators](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonimaging_optics). These were invented by [Roland Winston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_Winston), the person who literally wrote the book on non-imaging optics. I once attended a lecture by him and bought the book.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The OP used the word hyperbolic. I believe he is confused and CPCs are what he is looking for. I went to a lecture by Roland Winston who literally wrote the book about these and other non-imaging optics once upon a time.

Comment: that makes sense.  I'll delete my question

Answer (score 0):

Now i remember it, they're called Winston cones.

Comment: This would be more useful if you provided a link, a picture, and a brief discussion of how they work.